# Guessing game for comupter, fixing the high or low numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know i re-posted a question similar, but I changed the code and I'm having problems dealing with the guessing high or low. When I get the output it quits after a third guess and it gives a higher number or even lower number than before. my number is 8 and it will guess 12 and I say its High and gives 25 as the next guess. How would I fix that? How do I count the number of guesses too because it doesn't count?

```
from random import randint

def computer_guess(num):

    low = 1
    high = 100
    newGuess = 0
    guess = randint(1,100)
    while guess != num:
        newGuess = randint(low,high)
        print("The computer takes a guess...", newGuess)
        ans = input("Is the number L for low, H for High, or C for correct? ")
        if (ans == "H" or ans == "h"):
            if(high/2 > num):
                high = high/2
            else:
                high = high-1            


        elif (ans == "L" or ans == "l"):
            if(low*2 < num):
                low = low*2
            else:
                 low = low +1
        elif (ans == "C" or ans == "c"):
            ans = "Correct"
            guess = num;
            print(str(high) + "|" + str(low) + "|" + str(newGuess))


    print("The computer guessed", guess, "and it was correct!")
    print(" I computron won the battle")


def main():

    num = 0
    print("I am computron, I accept your guessing game!")
    num = int(input("\n\nChoose a number for the computer to guess: "))
    if num < 1 or num > 100:
        print("Must be in range [1, 100]")
    else:
        computer_guess(num)

    print("guesses count: " + str(num))


    play_again = input("would you like to play again(yes or no)? ")
    if play_again == "yes" or play_again == "y" or play_again == "Y":
        main()
    if play_again == "no" or play_again == "n" or play_again == "N":
        exit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that your initial high variable is set to 100. After a guess of 12 (using your example), it divides it by 2. The new high is 50. Therefore, 25 is still a valid guess. What you should do is to reset the new high variable to its guess:

```
if(ans == "H" or ans == "h"):
    high = newGuess
```

This will ensure that the next guess falls lower than its previous guess. A similar thing should be done to the low variable when it guesses low:

```
elif(ans == "L" or ans == "l"):
    low = newGuess
```

Comment: thank you ! It corrected the problem. What could I do for the count?

Comment: Set up a counter. Declare an int variable before the while loop and set it to 0. After that, Every loop through, at the beginning, add 1 to the variable by doing (for example, if the variable is i): i += 1. You can also have the function return the guess count, and you can print in main(), or just print it after winning in the function.